# How do i get python to run again?

Tags: new-operator

i just started learning python. today i tried to do some problems along with tutorials. somehwere along the way i do not know what i clicked to make it all stop working. originally it said it couldnt find my file, no matter what i typed in the code. i tried  clicking projects and making a new file but ended up deleting the files. I then tried to redownload it from the python website to restore factory settings and it says "verify that you have access to that directory. all code i write in google research collab works but once i put it in python i cant get anything to run.

i tried to reset python and also went to google to find what i did wrong. i think i somehow broke the path but i dont know to what